# React native bottom tabs tabBardBadge does not work

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am trying to put a badge head on a tab bar in React Native but it is not working.

Below is an example of my code:

**These are my module versions :**

```
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.14",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.1",
```

**This is my code :**

```js
      <Tab.Screen 
          name={'ApprovalTab'} 
          component={ApprovalScreen} 
          options={{tabBarBadge:3,
                    tabBarBadgeStyle:{color:'red'}}} 
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

         <Tab.Screen
          name={'ApprovalTab'}
          component={ApprovalScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarBadge: 0,
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <Ionicons name="home" color="red" size={30} />
            ),
          }}
        />
```

hope this will help you!!

Comment: First of all ,thanks for your comment but I am not trying to display icon over it ı need to put a number to display current number of unread notifications, nevertheless thanks for it.

Comment: like a notification ? in shopping app ?

Comment: If you visit https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/ that link and search tabBarBadge,you will understand what ı am trying to do.

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/?platform=web

Comment: like this ? you want ?

Comment: yes exactly, like this.

Comment: ok I'm using redux in shopping app if I  add 2 item to cart my cart tab bar display 3 badge in upon icon and I give this one to you way answer if you don't understand send your code then i will try

Comment: now see I updated the answer